Size increase spells vs Size change rules
I'm a little confused with how to apply "specific over generic" methodology to size-changing spells. I'm mostly thinking about:

Enlarge Person https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=enlarge%20person
Righteous Might https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=righteous%20might
Frightfull Aspect https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Frightful%20Aspect

...but the question is by no means exclusive to those.
Thing is, those spells list changes made to stats but those changes are in most cases not in line with changes mentioned in change size rules https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates/ or at the very least an incomplete subset of those.
Under "specific over generic" methodology one would assume spell description is what matters but... spells never mention those rules are overriding size change rules nor do they say changes listed are the only ones.
And I have no idea where that leaves me. Options I see are:

Add changes mentioned in spells and changes mentioned in generic rules combined.
Add changes mentioned in spells and only those changes mentioned in generic rules that weren't mentioned in spells.
Add only changes mentioned in spells and ignore changes mentioned in generic rules.
Something else entirely? Something I didn't consider?

Context for answers: RAW, only RAW, forever RAW.

For the most part, these spells don’t list the effects of changing size. They mostly list other effects in addition to changing the subject’s size. The effects of the size change are left to the generic rules for creature sizes. That is, yes, you get both the effects listed in the spell as well as the effects listed in the rules for your new size, because one of the effects of the spell is to give you that new size.
The one exception I see in several of these spells is the size modifier to attack and AC. Enlarge person and righteous might both mention that, even though it’s an effect of the size change. But righteous might just tells you to use the modifier appropriate to your new size. Frightful aspect doesn’t mention it (but you would still get it, since it’s part of being your new size).
So the real exception here is enlarge person, which specifies a −1 penalty to attack and AC. Basically, they assume the subject—a Humanoid—is Medium, and the spell has made them Large. This is problematic, since plenty of Humanoids are not Medium. I think this can only be understood as an error, but RAW, it is what’s written. And if we’re being that strict, what we have here is that you have two size modifiers: the one from enlarge person, and the one from your new size. RAW is murky here, though: typed bonuses don’t stack, and you’re meant to use the largest one. But that rule is specific to bonuses, and this is a penalty. RAW, all we have is “Penalties do not have a type and most penalties stack with one another,” which isn’t really helpful since this clearly does have a type, and “most” doesn’t tell us whether this is one of the “most” or not. (Both the bonus rule and the penalty rule are from Common Terms.) But without more to go on, the RAW answer is “the rules, as written, are ambiguous and require a DM ruling to sort out.”
But again, that’s only for enlarge person’s size modifier, nothing else.
